# Tkinter calculator program not working when i import it

Tags: python, tkinter, import, calculator

this is my first time on StackOverflow, and I'm stuck on this python calculator program.

The code works just fine when I run it standalone, but if I import this code in another script also having an instance of Tk(), it just doesn't do anything. The buttons worked fine as I checked them with print statements, I think there's a problem with the entry or the StringVar() variable.
I tried finding solutions to this but wasn't able to find anything related to this.

Here's the code:

```
from tkinter import *
exp=""
def press(num):
    global exp
    exp=exp + str(num)
    equation.set(exp)
def clrscr():
    global exp
    exp=""
    equation.set("")
def equalpress():
    try:
        global exp
        total=str(eval(exp))
        equation.set(total)
        exp=""
    except:
        equation.set('ERROR!')
        exp=""
win=Tk()
win.title('Calculator')
win.geometry('450x575')
win.configure(bg="#EAF0F1")
win.resizable(width=False, height=False)
equation=StringVar()
equation.set('Enter Value')
disp=Frame(win, width=500, height=100, bg="#dfe4ea")
entry=Entry(disp, width=33, textvariable=equation, font="Roboto 20", bg='#f1f2f6', foreground="#1e272e" )
entry.grid(padx=5, pady=5, ipady=20)
disp.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
btns=Frame(win, width=500, height=400, bg="white")
button1 = Button(btns, text=' 1 ', fg='black', bg='red', command=lambda: press(1), height=6, width=12) 
button1.grid(row=2, column=0) 

button2 = Button(btns, text=' 2 ', fg='black', bg='red',  command=lambda: press(2), height=6, width=12) 
button2.grid(row=2, column=2) 

button3 = Button(btns, text=' 3 ', fg='black', bg='red', command=lambda: press(3), height=6, width=12) 
button3.grid(row=2, column=4) 

button4 = Button(btns, text=' 4 ', fg='black', bg='red', command=lambda: press(4), height=6, width=12) 
button4.grid(row=3, column=0) 

button5 = Button(btns, text=' 5 ', fg='black', bg='red', command=lambda: press(5), height=6, width=12) 
button5.grid(row=3, column=2) 

button6 = Button(btns, text=' 6 ', fg='black', bg='red', command=lambda: press(6), height=6, width=12) 
button6.grid(row=3, column=4) 

button7 = Button(btns, text=' 7 ', fg='black', bg='red', command=lambda: press(7), height=6, width=12) 
button7.grid(row=4, column=0) 

button8 = Button(btns, text=' 8 ', fg='black', bg='red', command=lambda: press(8), height=6, width=12) 
button8.grid(row=4, column=2) 

button9 = Button(btns, text=' 9 ', fg='black', bg='red', command=lambda: press(9), height=6, width=12) 
button9.grid(row=4, column=4) 

button0 = Button(btns, text=' 0 ', fg='black', bg='red', command=lambda: press(0), height=6, width=12) 
button0.grid(row=5, column=0) 

plus = Button(btns, text=' + ', fg='black', bg='red', command=lambda: press("+"), height=6, width=12) 
plus.grid(row=2, column=6) 

minus = Button(btns, text=' - ', fg='black', bg='red', command=lambda: press("-"), height=6, width=12) 
minus.grid(row=3, column=6) 

multiply = Button(btns, text=' * ', fg='black', bg='red',command=lambda: press("*"), height=6, width=12) 
multiply.grid(row=4, column=6) 

divide = Button(btns, text=' / ', fg='black', bg='red', command=lambda: press("/"), height=6, width=12) 
divide.grid(row=5, column=6) 

equal = Button(btns, text=' = ', fg='black', bg='red', command=lambda: equalpress(), height=6, width=12) 
equal.grid(row=5, column=4) 

clear = Button(btns, text='Clear', fg='black', bg='red', command=lambda: clrscr(), height=6, width=50) 
clear.grid(row=6, columnspan=8) 

Decimal= Button(btns, text='.', fg='black', bg='red', command=lambda: press('.'), height=6, width=12) 
Decimal.grid(row=5, column=2)
btns.grid(sticky="nsew")
```

Comment: If you import this file from another python script with instance of `Tk()`, then it is an issue.

Comment: Yes I'm actually importing it in another program having Tk() too

Comment: It is better to have only one instance of `Tk()`.  So you need to change this `Tk()` to `Toplevel()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although you are allowed to have more than one master/root window, you shouldn't.
It introduces problems, as you can see. It's preferable to have one master/root. Because that's how it's treated.

Instead, use `TopLevel()` as acw1668 suggested. [Effbot's Documentation of TopLevel](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/toplevel.htm)

Otherwise, the problem is with the Entry, not the buttons. The buttons set the stringvar appropriately, but the entry does not get updated with that new value.

A cheap terrible solution is to put

```
def updateEntry():
    entry.delete(0,END)
    entry.insert(0, equation.get())
equation.trace_add("write", lambda *_ : updateEntry())
```

after you make the entry. But this adds more problems when you run the calculator by itself. Don't do it. Please.

I'm not sure what the other program does, but making it a toplevel is the best solution.

Comment: You can either changing `Tk()` to `Toplevel()` (recommended way) or setting master of `equation` to `win`, i.e. `equation = StringVar(master=win)`.